# How to center elements inside a div?

Tags: css

I have some divs inside a main div, but I have looked every questions similar to this and I have tried many things but I couldn't center them horizontally. I could only make them on the other side but not the center.

```
.ground {
  width: 390px;
  height: 575px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.line {
  padding: 10px
}

.active {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;  
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.nonactive {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  background: lime;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;  
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Here is the [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dw9v3v9c/)

You can see those 5 circles are the ones I need to center them inside the main div ground.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, the simplest way to do this would be to set the `display` of the `.line` element to `inline-block` so that it has a ["shrink-to-fit" width](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#lsquo). In doing so, it will have the same width as its children elements. Then add `text-align: center` to the parent element to center the inline child element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfu8p6fy/)

```
.ground {
  text-align: center;
}
.ground .line {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564) for a few alternatives.

Comment: Why not adding `text-align: center;` to .line ? I'm just asking a question :)

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh That would definitely work, but I thought it would be better to center the parent in case there was a background/border or something on it. For instance - http://jsfiddle.net/j30h4drb/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/vn409jkn/ Good point though.

Comment: This worked.. and I never came across the other thread you linked while searching for this problem.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Ah, I only thought of a direct answer than thinking of other situations. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of flexbox centering. `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` on the parent element will center the circles.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dw9v3v9c/1/)

```css
.ground {
  width: 390px;
  height: 575px;
  background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.line {
  padding: 10px
}
.active {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.nonactive {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  background: lime;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="ground">
  <div class="line">
    <div id="def" class="active"></div>
    <div id="def" class="active"></div>
    <div id="def" class="active"></div>
    <div id="def" class="active"></div>
    <div id="def" class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```